# Passing ASP.NET auth session from one webapp to another

Tags: asp.net, iis

Hope I can articulate this well.

I've a case where we've a front facing website hosted on IIS under a single application pool.

Now, we are to create an extension of the front facing website and the plan is to host it under a new application pool.

Some facts
* User auth uses ASP membership provider
* Users will login via the front facing site
* Front facing site is web forms based

Question:
Is there a way to seamlessly re-use the authenticated session from the front facing site to the sub-site (different IIS app pools)?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you give both applications the same machineKey it should work.

Some documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx